# Как произвести валидацию данных распарсенного CSV файла

Tags: php, csv, symfony, dto

Здраствуйте, Не могу понять как можно произвести валидацию данных распарсенного файла в обьекте транспортировки данных (DTO). Как я могу пропустить DTO через валидатор?
вот DTO:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Lots\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;
use Money\Currency;
use Money\Money;
use Money\MoneyParser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

final class LotImportDto
{
public Lot $lot;

#[Assert\Type(['string', 'null'])]
public ?string $number = null;

#[Assert\Type('string')]
private string $title = '';

#[Assert\Type(['string', 'null'])]
private ?string $description = null;

#[Assert\Type(['string', 'null'])]
private ?string $introtext = null;

#[Assert\Type('int')]
private int $qty = 1;

#[Assert\Type('array')]
private array $mapper = [
    'Lot Title'     => 'title',
    'Title'         => 'title',
    'Description'   => 'description',
    'Item Quantity' => 'qty',
    'Quantity'      => 'qty',
    'Qty'           => 'qty',
];

private LotRepository $lotRepository;

private MoneyParser $parser;

private SellerRepository $sellerRepository;

public function __construct(
    LotRepository $lotRepository,
    MoneyParser $parser,
    SellerRepository $sellerRepository,
    array $row
)
{
    $this->lotRepository = $lotRepository;
    $this->parser = $parser;
    $this->sellerRepository = $sellerRepository;
    $this->item = $row;
}

public function parseCSV(Auction $auction): void
{
    $currency = new Currency('USD');
    
    foreach ($this->item as $column => $value) {
        
        if (isset($this->mapper[$column])) {
            
            $property = $this->mapper[$column];
            // Do validation/casting on the value if need be
            switch ($property) {
                case 'qty':
                    $value = (int) $value;
                    
                    // Reset to default if the value is less than 1, i.e. an empty cell
                    if ($value < 1) {
                        $value = 1;
                    }
                    
                    break;
                
                case 'tax_exempt':
                    $value = strcmp('Yes', trim($value)) === 0;
                    
                    break;
            }
            
            $this->$property = $value;
        } elseif (strcmp(
            str_replace(
                ' ',
                '-',
                trim(strtolower($column))), 'seller')) {
            /** @phpstan-var positive-int $sellerNumber */
            $sellerNumber = (int) $value;
            
            // Try to find an existing seller for this event with this number otherwise generate a stub
            if (($seller = $this->sellerRepository->findSellerForEvent($auction, $sellerNumber)) === null) {
                $seller = Seller::createForAuctionWithNumber($auction, $sellerNumber);
                
                $auction->addSeller($seller);
                
                // Immediately add the seller to the database
                $this->sellerRepository->save($seller);
            }
            
            $this->seller = $seller;
        }
    }
}

public function isNew(Auction $auction): bool
{
    try {
        $this->lot = $this->lotRepository->findLotNumberForAuction($auction, $this->number);
        
        return FALSE;
    } catch (NoResultException) {
        $this->lot         = new Lot();
        $this->lot->number = $this->number;
        
        $auction->addLot($this->lot);
        
        return TRUE;
    }
}

public function getLotModel(): Lot
{
    $this->lot->title = $this->title;
    $this->lot->description = $this->description;
    $this->lot->introtext = $this->introtext;
    $this->lot->qty = $this->qty;
    $this->lot->status = $this->status;
    $this->lot->seller = $this->seller;
    $this->lot->sale_order = $this->sale_order;
    
    return $this->lot;
}
```

}

Comment: У вас тут намешано всё в одну кучу. В чем вопрос то ? Как валидировать дто ? Метод validate валидатора запустите.

Comment: @zalex Вы не могли бы показать, мне надо создать свой кастомный валидатор, или я могу использовать Symfony валидаторы?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: @zalex Спасибоя понял